# Foreach loop looping twice

Tags: php, foreach

So my problem is that it is looping twice and that is not the desired output that I wanted.So to start of I have a 3 checkbox with each value 1 till 3 which is sent to the database and is divided by a '@|@' sign.

Example of content for $rs_array['package'] for 3 checkboxes picked

```
1@|@2@|@3
```

Down here is the foreach loop of it

```
if(strpos($rs_array['package'], '@|@') == true){
$array = explode('@|@', $rs_array['package']);
foreach ($array as $myArray) {
    if ($myArray==1) {
        $myArray = "Starter";
    }
    elseif ($myArray==2) {
        $myArray = "Developing";
    }
    elseif ($myArray==3){
        $myArray = "Matured";
    }
    $my_Array[] =  $myArray;
}
//unset($my_Array);
$my_Arrays = implode(',', $my_Array);
}
else{

    $my_Arrays = $rs_array['package'];
    if($my_Arrays==1){
    $my_Arrays = "Starter";
    }
    elseif ($my_Arrays==2) {
        $my_Arrays = "Developing";
    }
    elseif ($my_Arrays==3) {
        $my_Arrays = "Matured";
    }
    else{
        $my_Arrays = "";
    }
}
echo $my_Arrays;
```

And down here is the output of the echo when I pick three of them

```
Starter,Developing,Matured,Starter,Developing,Starter,Developing,Matured
```

And here is when I pick two of them

```
Starter,Developing,Matured,Starter,Developing
```

I am still a rookie in this foreach field so do mind that I still can't figure a workaround or even why it display as such.Much help is appreciated

-------problem-----

Now I see the problem that is if I have only one row of $rs_array['package'] it works fine but the problem is if there is two or more.
It just adds up on the second one and so on...
and I need a way so that it identifies that each of those rows are different

Comment: Can you share the content of  `$rs_array['package']` ?

Comment: For the example shared `$rs_array['package'] = 1@|@2@|@3`. Your code works perfectly. Can you make sure you didn't miss anything in the question ?

Comment: I simulated your source code and it works fine. The problem lies on what manner you extracted the data. On my observation, you're calling this two times.

Comment: http://codepad.org/grKW7t4D works fine

Comment: @VenkataKrishna I added the whole of it but I dont think the else clause effects it?

Comment: @L.Herrera I see. I'll look more into my code then. Thanks for your quick response ^^

Comment: @nogad Hmmmm...I guess there is something wrong on my side then. Thanks for giving an example to boot.:)

Comment: I suspect that `$my_array` is not initialized (empty) before this section of code is entered. We don't see a function declaration, so we don't know what the scope of the variables is.  Or, `$rs_array['package']` does not contain the string you think it does. I suggest you add some debugging output (`var_dump`) of variables before and after the loop. If you think the foreach loop is being called twice, then the code that's causing that isn't shown. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @spencer7593 Thank you for replying^^. Thank you for your opinion. I'll test it to see what it gets before the loop.

Answer (score -2):

You can just directly push them on your array:

```
if(strpos($rs_array['package'], '@|@') == true){
     $array = explode('@|@', $rs_array['package']);
         foreach ($array as $myArray) {
             if ($myArray==1) {
               $my_Array[] = "Starter";
             } elseif ($myArray==2) {
               $my_Array[] = "Developing";
             } elseif ($myArray==3){
               $my_Array[] = "Matured";
             }    
         }
         //unset($my_Array);
         $my_Arrays = implode(',', $my_Array);
}
echo $my_Arrays;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, OP is asking why there is problem in his loop.